# Infinite loop when animating images

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ive got some code I'm using to fade images in and out of my project it works when its in another project but when its in the main project it gives me this error? If it makes any difference I'm using xib's still in my main project but I'm using storyboards in the test project where its working. Ive uploaded a screen shot and attached the website with the code so hopefully it might make some more sense to you guys.

http://alohacocoa.com/post/293647216/iphone-animation-fade-between-multiple-images

thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0xbf7fffdc)

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bc-r-LdCYAABd1O.jpg:large

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    backgroundImageQueue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [backgroundImageQueue addObject:
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"]];
    [backgroundImageQueue addObject:
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"]];

    /* Add any more images to the queue */
    backgroundB.image = [backgroundImageQueue
                         objectAtIndex:[backgroundImageQueue count] - 1];
    [backgroundImageQueue insertObject:
     backgroundB.image atIndex:0];
    [backgroundImageQueue removeLastObject];
    backgroundA.alpha = 1.0;
    backgroundB.alpha = 0.0;
    [self nextAnimation];
}

-(void)nextAnimation {
    backgroundA.image = backgroundB.image;
    backgroundB.image = [backgroundImageQueue
                         objectAtIndex:[backgroundImageQueue count] - 1];
    [backgroundImageQueue insertObject:
     backgroundB.image atIndex:0];
    [backgroundImageQueue removeLastObject];
    backgroundA.alpha = 1.0;
    backgroundB.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:6];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:
     @selector(nextAnimation)];
    backgroundA.alpha = 0.0;
    backgroundB.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: That looks like an infinite loop, not an error. Post your code (not a link to code that used to be the reference for your code)

Comment: Can you post more code than a screenshot...it is very hard to read.  You can post the code and add detail to show where the bad access is occurring...what variable is it on?

Comment: I've added the code on

Comment: I removed all the irrelevant code. The problem ist that the animation calls `nextAnimation` after it has stopped, and `nextAnimation` creates another animation. It is possible that this piece of code worked 4 years ago (when the blog post was written), but it does not work now. It just creates an infinite loop. I would suggest to find a different way to achieve the animation you need.

Comment: It works in another project in storyboards but not in xib's?

Comment: Bad advice: move `[self nextAnimation];` from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear:`. Apparently animations don't happen when the view has not appeared yet, and the stop selector is called immediately. Which leads to this infinite loop.

Comment: where would I find the viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 0):

well you should be able to look at your stack and it will say one of two things:

```
viewDidLoad
nextAnimation
(maybeSomethingElse)
viewDidLoad
nextAnimation
(maybeSomethingElse)
viewDidLoad
nextAnimation
(maybeSomethingElse)
viewDidLoad
nextAnimation
...
```

or

```
viewDidLoad
nextAnimation
(maybeSomethingElse)
nextAnimation
(maybeSomethingElse)
nextAnimation
(maybeSomethingElse)
nextAnimation
(maybeSomethingElse)
nextAnimation
...
```

which will give you a clue as to what is going on, is the view being loaded over and over, or is next animation just getting called recursively.

but I think that @matthiasBauch is correct that you need to move `[self nextAnimation]` to later in the view cycle